# How can I get a listing of all directories with videos on them?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

Using the Android `ContentResolver` I can get a `Cursor` that gives me video files, and that works nicely, but I see that a lot of apps separate that media by directory.

How do they figure out what directories have media without looping all of the items the `cursor` returns? Or is that the only way to do it?

Thanks.

Edit: Just to be clear, I already have code that queries all videos, loops through each one of them and extract the directories. Just seems silly that this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Check this project, this project might help you achieving what you wanted : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DirectorySelection

Comment: Thanks for but I just tried it and that isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Okay.. will let you know if I find something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to go from a cursor result to a list directly without looping. Cursors are lazy by design and don't have a native map functionality. Anko provides a parseList to abstract the loop (and close the cursor) and return you the desired list.

In re: the original question though. Due to there being multiple Uri buckets that content can live in (Documents, Downloads, etc) there isn't a single Uri to collate the result. You might be able to join the Uris in your query though?

Comment: Thanks for the info. That was my fear, just seems crazy that all apps that show all phone videos by folder are doing that but I guess that is the only way.

Comment: Yeah it really is a shame. You can kind of abstract it away with Kotlin but that just hides it from the surface.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution you are looking for is the FileNameFilter library which is provided by android only.You can do this like

```
File[] jpgfiles = f.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file)
        {
        return(file.getPath().endsWith(".mp4")||file.getPath().endsWith(".webm"));
        }
        });
```

// edited code//

```
File musicDirectory = new File( getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC));
```

// hope this one is you are looking for //

you can put different filers with it like other video files extentions.I like to add whichever directory has not media files have the file name .nomedia file which can be helpful too.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misread my question. I want to find all video directories using `ContentResolver` without looping each video `ContentResolver` has.

Answer (score 0):

I've already test.
 
Reference from [github](https://gist.github.com/vxhviet/bfcf54d060ee2b123c86fae2143dbbcf).

```
fun getPathList(): Array<String> {
        val uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA)
        val cursor = this.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
        val pathArrList = ArrayList<String>()

        cursor?.let {
            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                pathArrList.add(it.getString(0))
            }
            it.close()
        }
        return pathArrList.toTypedArray()
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see "without looping" .

Comment: Yeah that is also the code I have, seems really odd that so many apps present the data like this on the screen but that they have to do this looping in order to get it, surely there is a better way?

Comment: Currently, i still haven't found the other way yet.